# Is there a way to set a fixed scale in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology

In Arc, I am used to setting a fixed scale for the Data Frame, so when you zoom in and out the objects get larger or smaller. Is there a way to set a fixed scale in QGIS? At the moment, if you zoom in and out, the lines and text stay the same size.

I normally use ArcGIS, but we only have a single licence, so we are doing some research to using QGIS as a standby for some of our work.

Answer (score 16):

You can use Map Units for the size for the symbols and labels.  Now the Width of the symbol with be in the units of the maps.  In the example below 2 = ~2m

[image: Map units]

and in the label settings

[image]

Comment: I have found this works on lines, but any road names labelled on such a layer do not retain the fixed scale ability.

Comment: You have to also do this in the label settings (the ABC icon on the toolbar). See updated answer

Comment: Hi Nathan. Thanks for help on this question. I have one more that is related to what I am doing. I can colour the road names in CMYK, but can only colour the road polylines in RGB. Is there a way to access the CMYK sliders when colouring lines? Sean